# File appearing in mac that should be deleted

Tags: macos, apache

I am new to Apple products and I am following this tutorial http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/ so I can get a virtual host setup. I installed MAMP fine. I also followed the vhosts setup and all seems to working ok but it doesnt work once i load the page i.e mysite.local

After some playing about I removed MAMP from my machine and ran `sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`it brings up the last file i did have although i cannot find it in finder as I have removed MAMP from my system.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How did you remove (and install) MAMP?

Comment: Move to trash and emptied trash

Answer (score 0):

MAMP stores its configuration files at `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/` (see http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php), not at the default system location (`/etc/apache2/extra/`). You uninstalled MAMP correctly, but the guide had you editing the default Apache files that came with OS X, not the ones that MAMP uses.

Comment: It appears to be in a hidden private folder. So when i change my vhost file it must be that one i am changing instead of the mamp one. Would that be the problem?

Comment: I edited my answer -- turns out MAMP stored its files in a different location than the one you edited!